# Optimizing runtime (nested loop and shallow-Copy of Array)

Tags: python, runtime

Runtimefor the following code is too long.I am wondering if I want to optimize the code, should I find an alternative for nested loop OR shallow-copying of array is the reason.
I know the time complexity of nested loop is **O(n^2)** and time complexity of shallow copy is **O(n)**.Does it mean that reason of long runtime is the nested loop?

```
import copy

def rotLeft(a, d):
    
    size_a = len(a)
    
    temp_array = [0]* size_a
    
    for i in range (d):
        # Moving all elements to a new temp_array with updated indecies
        
        for j in range (size_a - 1):#0,1,2,3
            
            temp_array[j] = a[j+1]
            
        temp_array[size_a - 1] = a[0]#it is recognizing the a as the same as temp_array
        
        a = copy.copy (temp_array)#Shallow copy
        
#         print(a)
        
    for i in range (len(a)):
        
        print(a[i] , end = ' ')

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

d = 4

rotLeft(a, d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've implementing `rotLeft` by rotating the array `d` times. This means the runtime of your algorithm is O(d * n). You can avoid this by rotating the array by `d` from the start.

```py
def rotLeft(a, d):
    d = d % len(a)
    return a[d:] + a[:d]
```

`a[d:]` takes a slice of the input list starting from index `d`, and `a[:d]` takes the list from the first index to index `d`, which achieves the rotation you want. Concatenating the lists is an O(n) operation.

**EDIT:** Take the mod of the length of the list to handle cases where `d >= len(a)` or `d` is negative

Comment: What if d is greater than ```len(a)```? In that case slicing wouldnt work.right?

Comment: Ah yes that is true. You could mod it by `len(a)` to handle that.

Comment: What if I dont want to limit "d" to the length of array? My implementation was so. How can I improve runtime?

Comment: The mod operation should handle cases where d is greater than the length of your list. Rotating a length-5 list by 9 is equivalent to rotating it by 4. I've updated the answer to include the mod.